# Como hacer la esstructura de un array a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, array, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

**Tengo estos datos y necesito llevarlos a un array MySql**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Pensé en utilizar una tabla llamada tabulador con los siguientes campos: (id,origen, destino, km) pero no se si es muy productivo.

Comment: En vez de agregar una imagen, agrega el código que llevas, es más fácil para poder ejemplificar.

Comment: Es que no es código amigo.. es a estructura de la base de datos

Comment: Quieres pasar datos de un mysql a un array? o quieres un array dentro de mysql? o quieres pasar los datos de un array a un mysql?.....No se entiende nada la pregunta, podrías poner un poco más de información?